# Partition not reflecting correct size after growing disk space on EC2

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 hosted at Amazon Web Services. Initially my mounted volume was 8 GB and then I increased it to 16 GB. 
I went SSH'd into my Ubuntu Server and increased the partition size from 8 GB to 16 GB. But this isn't reflected anywhere.

```
lsblk
root@ip-***-**-**-**:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
loop1     7:1    0 12.7M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
loop2     7:2    0 87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5742
loop3     7:3    0 16.5M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/784
xvda    202:0    0   16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   16G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0    8G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0    8G  0 part
```

And then:

```
root@ip-***-**-**-**:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            481M     0  481M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  772K   98M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  5.9G  1.9G  77% /
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop1       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop2       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5742
/dev/loop3       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/784
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

```
xvda    202:0    0   16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   16G  0 part /
```

This indicates that your root partition is 16 GB. You will need to grow your filesystem too. If it is a ext4 filesystem it is something like:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```

After this, df -h should show root (/) to be near to 16 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I had to reboot my instance for the changes to apply.

Regardless, I noticed that my root "/" mount was on /dev/xvdf1 which was 8 GB. I increased the volume on AWS and then did `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvdf1` and my changes were reflected.